# Django's bulk_create doubts

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm adding this function to my Django app, but I have a couple of questions I need to know and which I couldn't find in Google.

1. Does it insert all records in the order the list is given? Or can they be suffle? Can I know which id corresponds to the index in the list of the items to give?
2. In case an error happened will it prompt which one failed, and will continue inserting the others, or will it stop inserting the rest of elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create), the `bulk_create` method inserts rows with the same order as in the list provided to it.

And also, based on the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/4.0.x/django/db/models/query.py#L561) the `bulk_create` uses an atomic transaction, so any errors would result in no rows adding to the db.